# How to clear out a saved password on iphone

Tags: password, iphone, ios, facebook

I have used the ESPN app using my Facebook credentials for quite awhile (years). Recently I logged out and let my friend log in, also using Facebook.

After she did her stuff she logged out. I went to log back in and when I clicked "Log in using Facebook" it automatically logged in using her Facebook account. I can't figure out how to clear this from the app's memory. There is no 'log in with a different account' option.

I have tried restarting my phone, deleting the app, deleting a few other ESPN related apps, made sure I am logged into my account on the Facebook app. I have looked in app permissions in Facebook and found nothing for either my account or my friend's.

I am confused why I could log off then my friend could log on and now it won't work in the other direction. How can I get the ESPN app to forget my friend's Facebook credentials.

I am on an iphone 6 running ios 10.2.1

Comment: Go to Facebook website in your browser and see if she is logged in. If so, log her out and log yourself back in. Then try ESPN again.

Comment: are you saving ESPN data with iCloud ?

Comment: I am not saving any ESPN data with iCloud. I did try logging her out both in the app and in a browser and neither worked. I did end up getting this fixed just by logging in to my ESPN elsewhere and getting my credentials through "Can't remember my username/password" then using them to log in.